# Laravel 5: route-model-binding not recognizing object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a `search()` method in `SubredditController`

```
public function search(Request $request, Subreddit $subreddit)
{
    $query = $request->input('search');
    $subreddit = Subreddit::with('posts.votes')->with('moderators.user')->where('id', 24)->first();
    $posts = $subreddit->posts()->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->get();
    $isModerator = $subreddit->moderators()->where('user_id', Auth::id())->exists();
    $modList = Moderator::where('subreddit_id', '=', $subreddit->id)->get();

    return view('subreddit.search', compact('query', 'subreddit', 'posts', 'isModerator', 'modList'));
}
```

As you can see `$subreddit` is getting all posts from subreddit ID 24 and the query works.

But when I replace 24 with `$subreddit->id` the query fails and gives null.

**EDIT:** Looks like it works on `$modList` because I have hardcoded it `24` in the first variable `$subreddit` but that still doesn't answer why `$subreddit->id` is inaccessible when it works fine on all other methods of the same controller

**EDIT 2:** I have also tried changing the `search` route to accept a parameter, like this `Route::post('search/{subreddit}')` but that gives the error `NotFoundHttpException` and the URL redirects to `localhost/reddit/public/search/%7Bsubreddit%7D` it's not recognizing any parameter.

**EDIT 3:** if I change the `search` route to `Route::post('subreddit/{id}/search', ...)` I get no errors, but `$subreddit->id` remains inaccessible and the URL points to `subreddit/%7Bid%7D/search` (with %7B characters)

These are my bindings

```
$router->model('subreddit', 'App\Subreddit');
$router->model('posts', 'App\Post');
$router->model('moderators', 'App\Moderator');
```

My Routes

```
Route::resource('subreddit', 'SubredditController');

Route::resource('subreddit.moderators', 'ModeratorsController');

Route::get('mysubreddits', [
    'as' => 'mysubreddits',
    'uses' => 'SubredditController@mySubreddits'
]);

Route::post('search', ['as' => 'search', 'uses' => 'SubredditController@search']);

Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
Route::resource('votes', 'VotesController');
Route::resource('profile', 'ProfilesController');
```

The view (which is a partial) from where I'm sending the search request

```
<h4>Search {{ $subreddit->name }}</h4>
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'SubredditController@search']) !!}
<div id="custom-search-input">
    <div class="input-group col-md-12">
        <input type="text" name="search" class="search-query form-control" placeholder="Search" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
                    <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </button>
            </span>
    </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: It works for the second because you're setting it (hardcoded to 24) in the first one. As for why it doesn't work in the first one, I don't know. But that should at least solve half of your problem.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. Now I just need to figure out why `$subreddit->id` isn't working at all, even though it works on all other methods in the same controller.

Comment: Try posting your routes file.

Comment: I've updated my original post.

Comment: Hmm I don't really know how resourceful controllers work so I can't help here. But it may be worth your editing out your confusion thing that I answered: it may make my comment look weird but it'll save people trying to answer that question for you.

Comment: Oh I've just realised that the specific route is the `search` one, and you don't specify any route parameters (`Route::post('search', ...);` ratehr than `Route::post('search/{subreddit}', ...)` so that's why it's not being populated. Right?

Comment: I tried that, I get this error `NotFoundHttpException` and the URI redirects to `localhost/reddit/public/search/%7Bsubreddit%7D` it's not recognizing any parameter.

Comment: Change this `Route::post('subreddit/{id}/search', ...)` to `Route::get('subreddit/{id}/search', ...)`  and change your search function to `search(Request $request,$id)`. Now you can use that id instead of 24. Do this `where('id', $id)'

Comment: @sixFingersMan this gives `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php`

Comment: Can you show your view from where you are sending request to search method??

Comment: @sixFingersMan I've updated my original post

Comment: @Halnex if you want to have a bound model you need to specify a route parameter. So if you do what i originally said that *would* work. However, it wasn't working for you as your form was not passing the subreddit parameter. So now you need `Form::open(['route' => ['search', $subreddit->getKey()]])` (I may be wrong about the format of the `Form::open` with route specified but you get the idea - you need to pass the ID in so that it turns into `/search/24` and so that your model can be bound correctly.

Comment: @alexrussell brilliant man, thank you. Please post an answer so I can select it as the correct one. :)

Comment: How you want to filter the subreddit ? I think it is not clear in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be assuming that typehinting a model will automatically somehow give you the model in your route. However a few things need to be done in order for route model binding to work:

1. You actually need to include the parameter in your route specification.
2. You need to ensure you pass the ID (or whatever field you you in your model binding function) in the URL.

So, given your code the following changes are required:

Route:

```
Route::post('search/{subreddit}', 'SubredditController@search')->name('search');
```

This actually adds a the placeholder for the parameter, and names it the same as your model's route binding.

(I have also taken the liberty of rearranging the line to not have the awkward options-as-array syntax, though depending on your Laravel version this may not be doable for you.)

View:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['search', $subreddit->getKey()]]) }}
```

This ensures that the first parameter to the route named `search` will contain the `Subreddit`'s ID (key) value.

These two things, together, will mean that the URI ends up being something like `/search/24` which will be converted into the `SubredditController@search` with method parameter typehinted as `Subreddit` pre-filled with a real model (ID of 24).

---

Note: if you don't wish to use IDs in your URIs but instead something like a `slug` field, you can still do this - bind your route as normal, but on your model define a `getRouteKeyName` method:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

And then just change the view's `Form::open` to this:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['search', $subreddit->getRouteKey()]]) }}
```

Again, this may be 5.1 specific and you may be using 5.0 which may or may not support doing it this way.

Comment: With the fact that Eloquent models appear to have `getRouteKeyName` and `getRouteKey` defined in the base `Model` class (going on the standard key name by default) it's quite likely that you'll find that you can just pass a model into the URI generation methods instead of, as I put here `$subreddit->getKey()` and $subreddit->getRouteKey()` and it automatically gets the value that is required. That is to say the following may work for you: `{{ Form::open(['route' => ['search', $subreddit]]) }}`.

Comment: thank you mate, yes indeed `$subreddit` works without `getKey()` however, I am trying the exact same thing you've shown me here on the Comments form. I am passing `$post` to the form and using `{post}` on the comment route. But I am still unable to access `$post->id` it's very confusing.